# How to change all key name inside nested array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have nested array of objects like bellow:

```
const data = [
  {text: 'node 1'}, 
  {text: 'node 2', chapter_playlist: [{text: 'node 2-1', lesson_playlist: [{text: 'node 3-1'}]}]},
  {text: 'node 3'}, 
  {text: 'node 4', chapter_playlist: [{ text: 'node 4-1' }]}
]
```

How to rename each nested property like **chapter_playlist**, **lesson_playlist** to '**children**' ?

basically I want to change the name of the property that has more children, if there are no children then there is no need to change it. And I'm still confused how to change it

**expected results**

```
const data = [
  {text: 'node 1'}, 
  {text: 'node 2', children: [{text: 'node 2-1', children: [{text: 'node 3-1'}]}]},
  {text: 'node 3'}, 
  {text: 'node 4', children: [{ text: 'node 4-1' }]}
]
```

Comment: Do you think you could provide valid JS code? Which properties do you want changed? Anything other than `id` and `title`? Anything that's an array? What if there are multiple properties that match your _children_ criteria?

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry if the question is incomplete, here I include a valid code along with the expected results
[https://jsbin.com/cenolun/edit?js,console](https://jsbin.com/cenolun/edit?js,console)

Comment: @Phil ok, edited, thank you

Comment: You've provided inputs and expected outputs. Where are your attempts? You also haven't answered the questions in my first comment

Comment: basically I want to change the name of the property that has more children, if there are no children then there is no need to change it. And I'm still confused how to change it

Comment: Hey @muhfaridzia, Tip for next time: you have to provide a code snippet of what you tried, that way, people can see what you're doing wrong or missing. If you just ask the question like this, it seems like you are asking for your question to be solved for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fun fact: if you need to walk through an object for whatever reason, [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) is your friend.

Not because you want to turn your data into a JSON string, but because it's also an object iterator that lets you perform arbitrary processing at every level using a [replacer function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#the_replacer_parameter):

```js
const data = [
  {text: 'node 1'}, 
  {text: 'node 2', chapter_playlist: [{text: 'node 2-1', lesson_playlist: [{text: 'node 3-1'}]}]},
  {text: 'node 3'}, 
  {text: 'node 4', chapter_playlist: [{ text: 'node 4-1' }]}
]

const rewriteList = [`chapter_playlist`, `lesson_playlist`];

function replacer(key, value) {
  // If the value at this depth is an object (but not an iterable
  // like array or Set or Map), then rebind the properties you
  // need rebound, provided they exist:
  if (typeof value === `object` && !value[Symbol.iterator]) {
    rewriteList.forEach(prop => {
      if (value[prop]) {
        // By editing "value", we're directly updating "data".
        value.children = value[prop];
        delete value[prop];
      }
    });
  }
  return value;
}

JSON.stringify(data, replacer);

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Nice! Didn't know that `JSON.stringify()` could be used like that. I just used `Array.reduce()` in my example.

Comment: So many people don't know that that second argument to JSON.stringify is _super_ powerful. Even folks who use `JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)` to get nicely formatted string output never seem to look up what that `null` actually refers to =P

Comment: thanks for the answer, already tried it earlier, and it worked.

It's true that there can be more than two children, if I use reduce it will be difficult, and the code will be harder to read.