# Set every object's array it's x index element

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

So I have an object like so that contains properties that are either and object (containing other objects untill it's not an object anymore) or an array of strings of text from english and french:

```js
let langs = {
    click : ["Click here", "Cliquez ici"],
    stat : ["Fonction status", "Status de la fonction"],
    no : ["Disabled", "Désactivé"],
    ping : {
        base : ["Pinging...", "Calcul du ping..."],
        result : ["Search complete, my latency is", "Recherche terminée, ma latence est de"]
    },
    kick : {
        error : {
            msg: [
                "I can't find this member, please check its writing or @!",
                "Je n'ai pas trouvé ce membre, veuillez vérifier son orthographe ou son @ !"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And the output I expect is :

```js
let langs = {
    click : "Click here",
    stat : "Fonction status",
    no : "Disabled",
    ping : {
        base : "Pinging...",
        result : "Search complete, my latency is"
    },
    kick : {
        error : {
            msg : "I can't find this member, please check its writing or @!"
        }
    }
}
```

My question : Is there a way to dynamically copy that object so that my output would be the exact same but with the arrays only be a string which is either the first or second element?
I know how to set an object's property to (for example) the first element

```js
let langs = { a : ["1","2"], b : ["3","4"] }
Object.keys(langs).forEach(n =>{
  langs[n] = langs[n][0]
})
console.log(langs)
```

But the object "langs" can not only be an array but also an object containing arrays or objects containing objects of arrays etc..
Would be awesome to have a function for this..

```js
let langs = { a : ["1","2"], b : ["3","4"] };
langs = onlySelectIndexElement(langs,0) // Or 1 if I want the second element etc..
```

Comment: Can you describe more what exactly you want to have as an output ?

Comment: The output is what i'm trying to get and the function who will give me the output is what i'm asking for (with an explanation) :/

Comment: Yeah but the output that you want to get is not clear. What is the question ?

Comment: You need a recursive function. It recurses into nested properties. When it gets to an array it returns the first element.

Comment: Oh here it's fixed @KarimChaari

Comment: Please correct `Clique ici` -> `Cliquez ici`, **AND** `Je n'est pas trouvé ce membre` -> `Je n'ai pas trouvé ce membre, veuillez vérifier son orthographe ou son @` for correct French sentences

Comment: You can do this with a one-liner, as long as you know that JSON.stringify is JS's built-in object walker (see answer). If you need _any_ kind of "run through an object and replace every X with Y", JSON.stringify will help you do that with barely any code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those cases where the built-in JSON library makes things a literal one liner:

```
let result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(langs, (key, value) =>
  value instanceof Array ? value[0] : value
));
```

And presto, we are done. The reason this works is because of the little known second argument to `JSON.stringify`, called the [replacer function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#the_replacer_parameter). We use that to just turn every array into "the first element in that array", and that's all we have to do. `JSON.stringify` does the actual recursive object walking for us.

Comment: When I discovered that it was like magic!

Comment: One of JS's best kept secrets. Even though it really shouldn't be =D

Answer (score 1):

You'd want a recursive function for this.

Map over the entries. If the value is an array, return the index. Otherwise, recursively run the value through the same function.

```js
const onlySelectIndexElement = (obj, index) =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).map(([ key, val ]) => [
      key, 
      Array.isArray(val) ? val[index] : onlySelectIndexElement(val, index)
    ])
  )

const langs = {"click":["Click here","Clique ici"],"stat":["Fonction status","Status de la fonction"],"no":["Disabled","Désactivé"],"ping":{"base":["Pinging...","Calcul du ping..."],"result":["Search complete, my latency is","Recherche terminée, ma latence est de"]},"kick":{"error":{"msg":["I can't find this member, please check its writing or @!","Je n'est pas trouvé ce membre, veuillez vérifier son écriture ou son @ !"]}}}
  
console.log("en", onlySelectIndexElement(langs, 0))
console.log("fr", onlySelectIndexElement(langs, 1))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: fun fact: if you need a recursive object walker, what you need [is JSON.stringify](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70030648/740553), with that magical second argument actually being used. If typeof value is an array, return array[0], otherwise, return the value itself. Done =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm not a fan of mutating the original but that's still pretty slick

Comment: I mean that's what that particular question asked for, but in this case we can just one-line it into a new var: `let result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(langs, (key, value) => value instanceof Array ? value[0] : value ));`

Answer (score 1):

Use a recursive function that returns the first element of the array when the value is an array, otherwise returns a new object where the property values are recursive calls to the function.

```js
let langs = {
  click: ["Click here", "Clique ici"],
  stat: ["Fonction status", "Status de la fonction"],
  no: ["Disabled", "Désactivé"],
  ping: {
    base: ["Pinging...", "Calcul du ping..."],
    result: ["Search complete, my latency is", "Recherche terminée, ma latence est de"]
  },
  kick: {
    error: {
      msg: [
        "I can't find this member, please check its writing or @!",
        "Je n'est pas trouvé ce membre, veuillez vérifier son écriture ou son @ !"
      ]
    }
  }
}

function mycopy(obj) {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    return obj[0];
  }
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => [key, mycopy(value)]));
}

console.log(mycopy(langs));
```